# filter products by attributes?

Tags: attributes

I can list all products in a CMS page using something like:

```
{{block type='catalog/product_list_promotion' template='catalog/product/list.phtml' toolbar_block_name='product_list_toolbar'}}
```

but is it possible to call the products using a block like that, while at the same time filtering on an attribute? In a ideal world, you would have a text saying attribute="my attribute name" filter="yes" but I'm guessing this doesn't exist? All googling shows so far is that I would need to custom code a new list.phtml

Is that correct? There's no quick shortcut through the admin, to filtering on an attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to solve this with the help of this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value

I basically added this:

```
    $_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'in_lager_list','eq'=>'1'),
));
```

to my list.phtml, and job done :)